# Math from left to right

Tags: python

So for an assignment, I need to have python do math from left to right.

from reading on here,
http://www.sthurlow.com/python/lesson02/

it says that "Also remember that the math is calculated from left to right, UNLESS you put in parentheses. The innermost parentheses are calculated first."

but is there anyway to force python to actually do math from left to right without parentheses and to ignore order of operations?

my code is simply just a variable and printing it after the user inputs the math equation

```
x = input("Enter numbers and operators: ")
print x
```

I need it to be able to do for example,
4 + 5 * 5 = 45

instead of 4+5*5 = 29 in python

any help is appreciated

edit 1

```
userinput = raw_input("Enter numbers and operators: ")
parts = userinput.split()
print parts
print eval(parts)
```

I input 1 + 1 and print it and result is ['1', '+', '1']   <---is this a considered a list?
I try eval(parts) and error says must be string or an object, should I be using "eval"?

Answer (score 6):

No. The point of the assignment is probably that you actually will have to write some code yourself rather than having python do everything for you, and that you have to learn how to use lists and loops. :-) Here is one possible approach:

1. Use `input()` to get the expression the user wants to evaluate. You will get this as one string, that is, one sequence of individual characters.
2. Split the string into a list of smaller strings, each being a number or an operator. So `"42 + 8 * 9"` should become `"42", "+", "8", "*", "9"`. (There is a built-in function called `split()` that does this, assuming that there are spaces between the operators and numbers.)
3. Create a variable, e.g. `result`, that will keep the result so far, and put the first number into it. Note that a string that contains digits is *not* the same as a number, but you can use `int()` to convert such a string into a number.
4. Use a `for` loop to look at the remaining elements of the list. Every time you find an element that is an operator, use that operation on `result` and the subsequent number from the list.

Try attacking the problem along these lines, and let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: I think he should be using `raw_input()` instead or Python will evaluate the input before he gets a chance to change the operator precedence rules :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker `raw_input` is spelled `input` in 3.x.

Comment: so simply i have
x = raw_input("Enter numbers and operators: ")
y = x.split()

i don't know how you would do step 3. Is there a way to do it without the for? like using while

Comment: @glors: Sure; `while` will do the trick as well. You might want to start with a simpler version of the task, to get comfortable with working with operators and numbers in this way. Assume that you will only get *one* operator, e.g. `42 * 9`. Try printing the result of `x.split()`; what does it look like? Can you obtain the two numbers somehow? What happens if you try to add the two numbers? Can you use `if` to check what kind of operator it is? Play around with it a little bit and update the question with what you have discovered.

Comment: @glors: By the way, you should use more descriptive names, such as `expression` instead of `x`, and `expressionParts` instead of `y`.

Comment: @glors: (re. first edit) Good. Indeed, `split()` gives you a list, and you're not supposed to use `eval()` (nor is it possible for this task). How can you extract an element from the list? What happens if you try to add the first and the last element? What happens if you utilize `int()`?